# Adding dynamic form elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to use jQuery to add the dynamic form elements to my page. At the moment I can get one of my form elements to be added when the user clicks the button but the second element isn't being added alongside it.

I do this by appending some html to divs with a specific class when a button is clicked.

I have created a JSfiddle. As you can see the 'ingredient' part is working, however the quantities is not.

https://jsfiddle.net/fe0t3by2/

```
$('.recipe-ingredients #addNewIngredient').on('click', function () {
        var i = $('.recipe-ingredients .ingredient').size() + 1;
        $('<div class="form-group ingredient"><label class="control-label" for="searchinput">Ingredients</label><div><input id="ingredient_' + i + '" name="ingredients[]" type="text" placeholder="Ingredients" class="form-control input-md"></div></div><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="pure-button pure-u-1-6 pure-button-primary" id="addNewIngredient">Add Ingredient</a></div>').appendTo($('.recipe-ingredients .ingredients'));
        $('<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="buttondropdown">Quantity</label><div class="input-group"><input id="quantity_' + i + '" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" type="text"><div class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Measure<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown pull-right"><li><a href="#">Grams</a></li><li><a href="#">Ounces</a></li><li><a href="#">Option three</a></li></ul></div></div>').appendTo($('.recipe-quantities .quantities'));
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Also why is the `Add Ingredient` button repeated

Comment: `ID`'s should be unique, you create multiple. Use `class` instead

Comment: You have a typo - `recipe-quantities`(js) vs `recipe-quantites`(class name) - missing `i` in `ties` - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dqvds66s/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fe0t3by2/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled the 'recipe-quantities' class on your quantities div.

```
<div class="col-md-6 recipe-quantites">
```

changed to

```
<div class="col-md-6 recipe-quantities">
```

Answer (score 0):

> At the moment I can get one of my form elements to be added when the user clicks the button but the second element isn't being added alongside it.

With *dynamically added content* you should `delegate` the click to the document for example (something where the object is contained in).

[jQuery documentation `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.recipe-ingredients #addNewIngredient', function () {
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fe0t3by2/2/)

Comment: This is correct, however I really doubt the user really wants to add new buttons every time. feels so odd

Comment: Totally agreed, it isn't user friendly at all. @Enjoyted